# Load rotated image in the same page

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have a django site and theres a page where the user clicks on a "Rotate image" button and the page should be reloaded with the image rotated.

The problem is that it works locally, but in production i'm having some problems (probably due to the time to upload and load the image again).

In the view, the code is like this:

```
def rotateLeft(request,idRedacao):
    obj = MyObject.objects.get(pk=idRedacao)       
    ...  
    original_photo = StringIO.StringIO(obj.arquivo.read())
    rotated_photo = StringIO.StringIO()

    image = Image.open(original_photo)
    image = image.rotate(90)
    image.save(rotated_photo, 'JPEG')

    path = obj.arquivo._get_path()
    obj.arquivo.delete()
    obj.arquivo.save(path , ContentFile(rotated_photo.getvalue()))
    obj.save()

    return render(request, 'theSamePageFromRequest.html',{"obj":obj,...})
```

Any idea of how to solve this problem?

Sorry for my bad english. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why don't u rotate it client-side and then push if when the rotating is done?

Comment: It's true.. Really better.. I will do this, thanks!

Comment: You appear to be rotating the image server side so there isn't a new upload happening. I think the problem you are seeing is merely caching. Remove all cache headers for the images that you are rotating. If they are already cached by browsers and proxies that might still not work. You might have to change the folder name.

Comment: @e4c5 I'm really noob in django.. How would i remove the cache headers for the images?

Comment: depends on how you are serving the images.

Comment: @RobertoAssunçãoFilho You're welcome :), ask for help if you want.